# How to debug lack of test caching

Tags: go, testing

I am running a Go test that I think should be cached when I run it more than once, however, Go is running the test every time.

Is there a flag or environment variable I can use to help determine why Go is deciding not to cache this particular test?

Comment: What exactly is the `go test` command you're running? The parameters you use affect whether results are cached or not. Also what makes you think they're not being cached?

Comment: I'm running a single test with `go test ./mypkg -run MySpecificTest`. When I run most tests more than once, I see `(cached)` in the output. When I run this test, I see the test time over and over indicating the test is being run more than once.

I'm a contributor to the Go language and I have spoken on stage at the main Go conference, about Go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `GODEBUG=gocachetest=1` in the environment, run the test twice and diff the output between test runs.

If that's not enough you can use `GODEBUG=gocachehash=1` to determine the components of the cache hash.

Comment: Was this actually a problem you were having when you posted it? Or is this just a case of "here's some knowledge I have, I'm going to phrase it as a question so I can post it"?

Comment: Yes, it was actually a problem I was having. I looked around for about 20 minutes before I posted the question, found the answer about 5 minutes later, and figured I would post it so I can remember in the future. The documentation around these flags is not good.